# GitLab installation on Debian Wheezy fails demanding initctl

Tags: linux, git, installation, chef-infra, gitlab

I'm using newly installed Debian 7 "Wheezy" on x86_64 and want to install GitLab. I followed the recommendation of the GitLab [README](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/README.md) file to download the packaged version for Debian Wheezy from [their download site](https://www.gitlab.com/downloads/). Afterwards I executed the following commands:

```
sudo dpkg -i gitlab_6.9.0-omnibus-1_amd64.deb
sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

The latter one fails with the following message:

```
================================================================================
Error executing action `run` on resource 'execute[initctl status gitlab-runsvdir]'
================================================================================

Errno::ENOENT
-------------
No such file or directory - initctl

Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/runit/recipes/upstart.rb

29: execute "initctl status gitlab-runsvdir" do
30:   retries 30
31: end
32: 

Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/runit/recipes/upstart.rb:29:in `from_file'

execute("initctl status gitlab-runsvdir") do
  action "run"
  retries 0
  retry_delay 2
  guard_interpreter :default
  command "initctl status gitlab-runsvdir"
  backup 5
  returns 0
  cookbook_name :runit
  recipe_name "upstart"
end
```

I think that the missing command `initctl` is part of `systemd`. But Debian Wheezy is using the classic SysV init system and not `systemd`.

I'm looking for a way to make this installation work. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

omnibus-gitlab is hoping to use upstart on your system (see the recipe_name) but that is not working somehow. Could you create an issue at https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues ? (Requires a gitlab.com account.)

Comment: I created a bug report here: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/134

Comment: Thanks; I will continue there.

Comment: There was a bug in the installer. jacobvosmaer fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed and the packages where updated, see https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/134

Comment: I opened that ticket by myself, as documented in the comments of jacobvosmaer's answer.

Comment: aef, I noticed that, thanks, just leaving a comment here for future people